# verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature:

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I have used ad-hoc distribution for my iPhone app many times before, and successfully. But now I have ran into an error that I cannot solve. When installing the app on the device, the "download bar" goes almost all the way, but then fails. A failure popup comes up on the device.
When I monitor the device console log, these are the first error messages that come:

```
Apr  8 20:18:27 unknown installd[386] <Error>: 2ffd6000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394
Apr  8 20:18:27 unknown installd[386] <Error>: 2ffd6000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.OV4ox9/foo_extracted/Payload/Flyskyhy.app
Apr  8 20:18:27 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[379] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Apr  8 20:18:27 unknown installd[386] <Error>: 2ffd6000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Apr  8 20:18:29 unknown installd[386] <Error>: 2ffd6000 handle_install: API failed
```

I have no idea what this means, or how to debug this. Does anybody know how to solve this?

What I have tried already:

- verify that the provisioning profile and certificates are correct and not expired
- create a new distribution profile, enabled the device for it, download it into XCode, and do a new Archive and Distribute with that
- delete all distribution profiles from the device (the new one is the only one on the device now)
- restarted XCode and did a complete new rebuild.
- completely removed the app from the device before installing again.
- searched the web for people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it work now. I am not sure how, though. I did some small changes to the app, stepped the version number and distributed that in the same way as before. Now it managed to install correctly.

One other thing that I did, is to remove the old app completely from the phone before doing the new install. I did not manage to do that before, it always remained on the phone with its icon in half-loaded state. Now I did a combination of Remove from iTunes and clicking the 'x' delete icon multiple times, and it finally disappeared completely.